# Combining rows on a query in access 2010

Tags: ms-access

First off I know nothing about VB and the post I have seen on here refer to that, I am sure that this is a very simple thing to do so please help

I am trying to hve my TN Route be my primary key/no duplicates and have date driver 1 driver 2 and driver 3 all in diff cells and all side by side, and even though the tbl that it is pulling from the TN route is primary, it keeps adding additional rows for each driver.

See attached screenshot:

Thank you in advance.
Stan

[data sheet view of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WcZF.jpg)

Comment: The table isn't correctly designed. It should have just one column for the driver's name, and then a column indicating what category of driver they fall into. It's possible to write a query to collapse these rows; but the preferable method would be to rearrange the table structure and then built a report off of it.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please avoid abbreviations like "tbl", put some effort on your language and separate your question into: what you try to achieve, how your current situation looks like and what kind of error occurs, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That image is the table? If you want 3 drivers for each TN Route and Date pair then why aren't you entering the data in table that way? Should not use Date as a field name because it is an intrinsic function.

Comment: The data come to me this way exported from SAP, and I import it into access table.

Answer (score 0):

This query will do it for you. Again, it's not preferable because in Access SQL tends to be a little messy on account of it not having features that more robust SQL platforms do - but it will work. You'll need to change the name of your **Date** column to **Route Date** in order for this to work, and replace my **tblTest** with whatever your table name is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblTest.[TN Route], tblTest.[Route Date], tA.[Driver 1], tB.[Driver 2], tC.[Driver 3]
FROM ((tblTest LEFT JOIN (SELECT tblTest.[TN Route], tblTest.[Route Date], [Driver 1] FROM tblTest WHERE [Driver 1] <> '')  AS tA ON (tblTest.[Route Date] = tA.[Route Date]) AND (tblTest.[TN Route] = tA.[TN Route]))
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT tblTest.[TN Route], tblTest.[Route Date], [Driver 2] FROM tblTest WHERE [Driver 2] <> '')  AS tB ON (tblTest.[Route Date] = tB.[Route Date]) AND (tblTest.[TN Route] = tB.[TN Route]))
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT tblTest.[TN Route], tblTest.[Route Date], [Driver 3] FROM tblTest WHERE [Driver 3] <> '')  AS tC ON (tblTest.[Route Date] = tC.[Route Date]) AND (tblTest.[TN Route] = tC.[TN Route])
```

In Access 2010, go Create > Query Design > add your table, and then paste the SQL into the SQL view of the query designer. You can even make a standalone table out of the result.